Set a proxy between Consumer Connector and Provider Connector
I'm trying to configure with some customization this repository called [MVD] eclipse-edc/MinimumViableDataspace. I do these steps first from README then being completed, their docker containers starts:
3 EDC Connectors company1 company2 company3 A Registration Service A HTTP Nginx Server (to serve DID Documents) An Azurite blob storage service
I'm trying to set up a proxy server (with Nginx) between the Consumer connectors (EDC Connectors) and the Provider Connector (Azurite).
This is my nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass example.com:10000; # The Azurite server address
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

My problem is that the connectors can send files to the azurite and the proxy server is not working or showing anything at all.
docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:

  company1:
    container_name: company1
    build:
      context: ../launchers/connector
      args:
        JVM_ARGS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005"
    environment:
      EDC_DSP_CALLBACK_ADDRESS: example.com:8282/api/dsp
      EDC_CONNECTOR_NAME: company1
      EDC_PARTICIPANT_ID: did:web:did-server:company1

      EDC_BLOBSTORE_ENDPOINT_TEMPLATE: "example.com:8080/%s" # Using proxy to go to the azurite
      EDC_IDENTITY_DID_URL: did:web:did-server:company1
      EDC_VAULT: /resources/vault/company1/company1-vault.properties
      EDC_KEYSTORE: /resources/vault/company1/company1-keystore.jks
      EDC_SELF_DESCRIPTION_DOCUMENT_PATH: /resources/self-description/company1/sdd.json
      EDC_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: test123
      EDC_API_AUTH_KEY: ApiKeyDefaultValue
      EDC_IAM_DID_WEB_USE_HTTPS: "false"
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_EXECUTION_DELAY_SECONDS: 5
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_EXECUTION_PERIOD_SECONDS: 5
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_PARTITION_NUM_CRAWLERS: 5
      EDC_DATAPLANE_TOKEN_VALIDATION_ENDPOINT: example.com:8383/api/control/token
      REGISTRATION_SERVICE_API_URL: example.com:8184/api/authority
      EDC_WEB_REST_CORS_ENABLED: "true"
      EDC_WEB_REST_CORS_HEADERS: "origin,content-type,accept,authorization,x-api-key"
    depends_on:
      - did-server
      - azurite
      - registration-service
    ports:
      - "9191:9191"
      - "8181:8181"
      - "5005:5005"
      - "7171:7171"
    volumes:
      - ./resources:/resources

  company2:
    container_name: company2
    build:
      context: ../launchers/connector
      args:
        JVM_ARGS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5006"
    environment:
      EDC_DSP_CALLBACK_ADDRESS: example.com:8282/api/dsp
      EDC_CONNECTOR_NAME: company2
      EDC_PARTICIPANT_ID: did:web:did-server:company2

      EDC_BLOBSTORE_ENDPOINT_TEMPLATE: "example.com:8080/%s"
      EDC_IDENTITY_DID_URL: did:web:did-server:company2
      EDC_VAULT: /resources/vault/company2/company2-vault.properties
      EDC_KEYSTORE: /resources/vault/company2/company2-keystore.jks
      EDC_SELF_DESCRIPTION_DOCUMENT_PATH: /resources/self-description/company2/sdd.json
      EDC_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: test123
      EDC_API_AUTH_KEY: ApiKeyDefaultValue
      EDC_IAM_DID_WEB_USE_HTTPS: "false"
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_EXECUTION_DELAY_SECONDS: 5
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_EXECUTION_PERIOD_SECONDS: 5
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_PARTITION_NUM_CRAWLERS: 5
      EDC_DATAPLANE_TOKEN_VALIDATION_ENDPOINT: example.com:8383/api/control/token
      REGISTRATION_SERVICE_API_URL: example.com:8184/api/authority
      EDC_WEB_REST_CORS_ENABLED: "true"
      EDC_WEB_REST_CORS_HEADERS: "origin,content-type,accept,authorization,x-api-key"
    depends_on:
      - did-server
      - azurite
      - registration-service
    ports:
      - "9192:9191"
      - "8182:8181"
      - "5006:5006"
      - "7172:7171"
    volumes:
      - ./resources:/resources

  company3:
    container_name: company3
    build:
      context: ../launchers/connector
      args:
        JVM_ARGS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5007"
    environment:
      EDC_DSP_CALLBACK_ADDRESS: example.com:8282/api/dsp
      EDC_CONNECTOR_NAME: company3
      EDC_PARTICIPANT_ID: did:web:did-server:company3

      EDC_BLOBSTORE_ENDPOINT_TEMPLATE: "example.com:8080/%s"
      EDC_IDENTITY_DID_URL: did:web:did-server:company3
      EDC_VAULT: /resources/vault/company3/company3-vault.properties
      EDC_KEYSTORE: /resources/vault/company3/company3-keystore.jks
      EDC_SELF_DESCRIPTION_DOCUMENT_PATH: /resources/self-description/company3/sdd.json
      EDC_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: test123
      EDC_API_AUTH_KEY: ApiKeyDefaultValue
      EDC_IAM_DID_WEB_USE_HTTPS: "false"
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_EXECUTION_DELAY_SECONDS: 5
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_EXECUTION_PERIOD_SECONDS: 5
      EDC_CATALOG_CACHE_PARTITION_NUM_CRAWLERS: 5
      EDC_DATAPLANE_TOKEN_VALIDATION_ENDPOINT: example.com:8383/api/control/token
      REGISTRATION_SERVICE_API_URL: example.com:8184/api/authority
      EDC_WEB_REST_CORS_ENABLED: "true"
      EDC_WEB_REST_CORS_HEADERS: "origin,content-type,accept,authorization,x-api-key"
    depends_on:
      - did-server
      - azurite
      - registration-service
    ports:
      - "9193:9191"
      - "8183:8181"
      - "5007:5007"
      - "7173:7171"
    volumes:
      - ./resources:/resources

  newman:
    container_name: newman
    image: postman/newman:ubuntu
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: deployment/seed-data.sh
    volumes:
      - ../deployment/:/deployment
    working_dir: /
    environment:
      API_KEY: ApiKeyDefaultValue
      EDC_HOST: company1:company2:company3
      ASSETS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT: company1assets:company2assets:company3assets
      PARTICIPANT_ID: company1:company2:company3
    depends_on:
      company1:
        condition: service_healthy
      company2:
        condition: service_healthy
      company3:
        condition: service_healthy

  did-server:
    container_name: did-server
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./resources/webdid:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "7070:80"
  
  proxy-server:
    container_name: proxy-server
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf  # Configuration file
    ports:
      - "8080:80"  # Server on port 8080

  azurite:
    container_name: azurite
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    ports:
      - 10000:10000
    environment:
      AZURITE_ACCOUNTS: company1assets:key1;company2assets:key2;company3assets:key3
    depends_on:
      - proxy-server

  registration-service:
    container_name: registration-service
    build:
      #e.g. /home/user/RegistrationService/launcher
      context: ../launchers/registrationservice
      args:
        JVM_ARGS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5008"
    environment:
      JWT_AUDIENCE: example.com:8184/api/authority
      EDC_IAM_DID_WEB_USE_HTTPS: "false"
      EDC_CONNECTOR_NAME: registration-service
      EDC_IDENTITY_DID_URL: did:web:did-server:registration-service
      EDC_SELF_DESCRIPTION_DOCUMENT_PATH: /resources/self-description/registration-service/sdd.json
      EDC_VAULT: /resources/vault/registration-service/registration-service-vault.properties
      EDC_KEYSTORE: /resources/vault/registration-service/registration-service-keystore.jks
      EDC_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: test123
      EDC_ERROR_RESPONSE_VERBOSE: "true"
    ports:
      - "8184:8184"
      - "8185:8181"
      - "5008:5008"
      - "7174:7171"
    volumes:
      - ./resources:/resources

  cli-tools:
    container_name: cli-tools
    build:
      context: ./resources/cli-tools
    volumes:
      - ./resources:/resources
      - ../resources:/common-resources
    depends_on:
      company1:
        condition: service_healthy
      company2:
        condition: service_healthy
      company3:
        condition: service_healthy
      registration-service:
        condition: service_healthy

  company1-datadashboard:
    container_name: company1-datadashboard
    build:
      context: ${MVD_UI_PATH}
    volumes:
      - ./resources/appconfig/company1:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config
    depends_on:
      company1:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "7080:80"
    profiles: ["ui"]

  company2-datadashboard:
    container_name: company2-datadashboard
    build:
      context: ${MVD_UI_PATH}
    volumes:
      - ./resources/appconfig/company2:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config
    depends_on:
      company2:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "7081:80"
    profiles: ["ui"]

  company3-datadashboard:
    container_name: company3-datadashboard
    build:
      context: ${MVD_UI_PATH}
    volumes:
      - ./resources/appconfig/company3:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config
    depends_on:
      company3:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "7082:80"
    profiles: ["ui"]

My objective is to make a data transfer, example file initiate-transfer.md but with the proxy in the middle.
Despite configuring the proxy server, the EDC Connectors can send files to Azurite, but the proxy server doesn't seem to work or display any activity.
